# Extract date from "Mon Jan 12 06:20:06 IST 1976"

Tags: java, date

I've a `datetime` with value

```
"Mon Jan 12 06:20:06 IST 1976"
```

How can I extract just the date from it?

```
12 Jan 1976
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to first search for existing questions my friend. I'm pretty sure that this question is already answered by a lot many people.

Comment: It is never the same date everywhere on Earth. Is it OK to get the date in the same time zone as in the string (whatever IST means, it’s ambiguous)?

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. You can assume all the basic questions on date-time have already been asked and answered.

Comment: @EistonDsouza :) I stopped posting questions at all.

Answer (score 4):

Using [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in Java 8, you can easily do the parsing.

```
String s = "Mon Jan 12 06:20:06 IST 1976";
ZonedDateTime localDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"));
```

And you can generate `String` objects, automatically [localized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization).

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);

String date = dateFormatter.format(localDateTime.toLocalDate());
String time = timeFormatter.format(localDateTime.toLocalTime());
```

> Jan 12, 1976
>
> 6:20:06 AM